# MYSQL: How to select only users who signed up today

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that I can check whether the linux timestamp in $time is today by doing this:

```
date("d-m-Y")==date("d-m-Y", $time);
```

But i want to use this in a select query to grab only users who signed up today like:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE time = <TIMEISTODAY>";
```

time is an int in the user table that stores a linux time stamp.

I know i can filter the results AFTER selecting all users...but there's certainly a better way..i just don't know it..Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = DATE(NOW())
```